# Issues and things to be concerned when upgrading Active Reports from version 3 to version 10

Tags: activereports

Issues and things to be concerned when upgrading Active Reports  from version 3 to version 10 . I am not familiar with Active reports and need to investigate over this . It would be great if I get some info and from there I can take over . Some usefuls links . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some useful links that will help you upgrade from version 3 to version 10:
http://arhelp.grapecity.com/webhelp/AR10/index.html#Upgrading%20Reports.html
http://arhelp.grapecity.com/webhelp/AR10/index.html#BreakingChanges.html

The namespaces were changed from version 7 onwards, so you'll probably need to change few namespaces in the reports.

Comment: Thank you team . I had also raised a ticket in your site and got reply from the team . Thanks for the reply .

Comment: Glad to know you got the answer you were looking for :)